# Радиальное меню на CSS и JS

Tags: jquery, css3

поступила задача сделать как на картинку для пк[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

необходимо чтобы при наведении изменялся задний фон и появлялся текст относящийся к элементу. всего 9 элементов.

в мобильной версии должно выглядеть как на картинке ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в мобильной версии мне понятно. Тут унас аккордеон.

проблема: Я не знаю как реализовать десктоп вариант.

Его необходимо реализовать таким образом, чтобы потом в мобильную версию в аккордеон переделать было легко, не создавая заново для мобильного этот дизайн (если возможно).

Верстаю бутстрапом 3, канвас не знаю, CSS3 средний уровень, js начальный, пользуюсь готовыми скриптами jquery.

Подскажите путь.

п.с. небольшой образец и дайте направление кто знает.

Comment: А вы хоть верстальщик?

Comment: @razmik-galstyan http://zaddys.moorsoftware.com/
http://blogtmp.com/av/lp1/
хватит или мне сейчас вспоминать?

Comment: @razmik-galstyan что замолчали-то? есть мысля? достаточно, просто сделай так, вот так, привести примерный образец. Дальше я сам. вся моя проблема заключается в крıвом диве этом и при ховере появление бордера. могу конечно это все картинками залепить, absolute, transform:rotate, z-index и т.д. но каша же будет. ))

Comment: Научитесь уважать других, и еще вы не просто проблему отдельную хотите что бы здесь решили, а целый `task`.

Comment: @razmik-galstyan а я никого и не оскорблял и не намеревался. я не прошу все решить за меня )) я прошу как раз решение. Дать направление. кто сталкивался или знает. У более опытных. Я не профи в верстке. Я только junior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот заготовочка:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
:root {
  --bg: #f00;
  --angle: 0deg;
  --radius: 300px;
  --inner-radius: 160px;
  --digit-radius: 45px;
}
div > b {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: solid var(--bg) var(--radius);
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%);
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: 50% var(--radius);
  z-index: 1;
}
div > b::after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -350px;
  left: -60px;
  width: calc(var(--digit-radius) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--digit-radius) * 2);
  border-radius: calc(var(--digit-radius) * 2);
  background: #fff;
  padding: calc(var(--digit-radius) * 0.7) 0 0 calc(var(--digit-radius) * 0.7);
  content: var(--digit);
  transform: rotate(calc(360deg - var(--angle)));
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: calc(var(--digit-radius) * 2);
  color: var(--bg);
  z-index: 3;
}
div > p {
  padding: calc(var(--inner-radius) * 0.4);
  width: calc(var(--inner-radius) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--inner-radius) * 2);
  border-radius: calc(var(--inner-radius));
  margin: calc(- var(--inner-radius));
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(var(--radius) - var(--inner-radius));
  top: calc(var(--radius) - var(--inner-radius));
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
div > b:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}
div > b:hover + p,
p:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div><p style="visibility: visible;">text 0</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #f00; --angle: 0deg; --digit: '1';"><b></b><p>text 1</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #0f0; --angle: 45deg; --digit: '2';"><b></b><p>text 2</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #00f; --angle: 90deg; --digit: '3';"><b></b><p>text 3</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #ff0; --angle: 135deg; --digit: '4';"><b></b><p>text 4</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #0ff; --angle: 180deg; --digit: '5';"><b></b><p>text 5</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #f0f; --angle: 225deg; --digit: '6';"><b></b><p>text 6</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #4c4; --angle: 270deg; --digit: '7';"><b></b><p>text 7</p></div>
<div style="--bg: #44c; --angle: 315deg; --digit: '8';"><b></b><p>text 8</p></div>
```

Просчитать паддинги для каждой цифры, разместить дополнительные картинки, а также пересчитать с 8 на 9 секций — вам домашнее задание. Общий принцип построения должен быть понятен.

Тестировалось в Firefox. Возможно, в других браузерах потребует префиксов.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать селектор в CSS, все делается достаточно просто и аккуратно. Псевдокласс :hover (при наведении курсора применяется необходимый стиль)
http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover

Comment: Спасибо это я понял. задам более конкретно вопрос. возможно ли задать див таким образом как секция на картинке  для пк (к примеру возьмем секцию 9)

Comment: Уточните вопрос, не могу понять какого результата вы хотите добиться.